# VAR on I(1) and I(3) time series

Tags: time-series, econometrics, multivariate-analysis

[image]
I want to analyze the effect of interest rate to exchange rate with VAR. After some unit root and stationarity tests (ADF, PP, KPSS), all of the exchange rate time series are I(1) series, whereas interest rates are I(3) series (the attached graph shows the interest rate series).

Is it still possible to use VAR with the 1st difference of exchange rate and the 3rd difference of interest rate? Feel free to give any suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not aware of any result in the literature saying that exchange rates (or for that matter any other variable) are I(3), so I would be very skeptical of an analysis that differences three times.

Comment: the exchange rate is I(1) but the interest rate is I(3) based on KPSS test

Comment: I understand that this is what the tests say in your case, but I suspect that this result is driven by something else which invalidates the conclusion of the KPSS test, i.e. violation of some underlying assumption. Have you plotted the data? I(3) data would be *extremely* explosive, which I doubt your interest rates are.